# cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' in manim Linux ( Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, manim

```
soutrik@soutrik-X541UJ:~/manim-folder/manim$ python3.7 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manim.py", line 2, in <module>
    import manimlib
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manimlib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import manimlib.extract_scene
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manimlib/extract_scene.py", line 9, in <module>
    from manimlib.scene.scene import Scene
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 11, in <module>
    from manimlib.camera.camera import Camera
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manimlib/camera/camera.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

so i tried to open the camera.py and change the PIL to pillow and then it shows this

```
soutrik@soutrik-X541UJ:~/manim-folder/manim$ python3.7 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manim.py", line 2, in <module>
    import manimlib
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manimlib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import manimlib.extract_scene
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manimlib/extract_scene.py", line 9, in <module>
    from manimlib.scene.scene import Scene
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 11, in <module>
    from manimlib.camera.camera import Camera
  File "/home/soutrik/manim-folder/manim/manimlib/camera/camera.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pillow import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

so no module huh? but if i do `python3.7 -m pip install pillow` I get

```
soutrik@soutrik-X541UJ:~/manim-folder/manim$ python3.7 -m pip install pillow
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (7.0.0)
```

I also tried Pillow

```
soutrik@soutrik-X541UJ:~/manim-folder/manim$ python3.7 -m pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (7.0.0)
```

so how do i install it inside this manim folder ? or do i not need to do that ? do i need to add something to $PATH ? i am relatively new to Linux but even back in windows i didnt know much about PATH just added python3.7 to it to access from anywhere but in linux i can access python from anywhere without addidn to path ( did it automatically add to path ) so maybe its because pillow is not added to path since i cant use it from manims folder

also i tried to install PIL

```
soutrik@soutrik-X541UJ:~/manim-folder/manim$ python3.7 -m pip install PIL
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
```

---------------------EDIT-1--------------------------
when in home directory and i run 
`>>>from PIL import Image`

I get

```
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, doing this resolved my issue

```
pip install -U Pillow
```